# Ruby on Rails download pdf link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering if there is a helper method, which can create a link to download a pdf file?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to generate a PDF you will need to use something like [Prawn](http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn) or [PDFKit](http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit). If you simply need to link to an existing PDF, just use `link_to`.

Comment: can you please share your answer. I am having the same problem.